# Problem with write dataframe into blob storage in Azure

Tags: pandas, dataframe, azure, databricks

I am trying to write a pandas dataframe to a blob storage in Azure with Databricks. I am able to make the connection to the blob storage, but I am not able to write my dataframe with the BlobClient library of "azure.storage.blob".

I've read tutorials on the internet, but they have deprecated libraries, and I can't find a current solution. I am using version "azure-storage-blob==12.12.0" and my code is as follows:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient
import pandas as pd
import io

output = io.StringIO()
head = ["col1" , "col2" , "col3"]
l = [[1 , 2 , 3],[4,5,6] , [8 , 7 , 9]]
df = pd.DataFrame (l , columns = head)
print(df)
output = df.to_csv (index_label="idx", encoding = "utf-8")
print(output)

accountName = "https://xxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/"
accountKey = 'xxxxxx'
containerName = "mycontainer"
blobName = "test3.csv"

blobService = BlobClient(account_url=accountName, account_key=accountKey, container_name="mycontainer", blob_name = blobName, output)  # <-----HERE IS THE PROBLEM
```

What am I doing wrong?

Do you have an example that can work with my current version please?

Many thanks in advance.

Regards

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Did you try mounting the storage?

Read More here

https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/azure/azure-storage.html

Comment: Thanks you for response. I did try investigate about your commentary, about how mount blob storage in databricks, but I dont know how mount correly, the secret scope say "value":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.""